# Add system permission to installed app

Tags: android

I have the following problem.
I require my app to have android.permission.BIND_VPN_SERVICE, but as it is a self signed app, the android system does not allow this permission.
I tried to use adb to add the permission but that is not allowed either. 
Is there a way to add this permission to my app, after it is installed?

It is running inside an genymotion emulator, so I have root access.
Additionally I can switch to different Android versions.

Any idea is appreciated.

best regards,
Alex

Comment: At least on Android 7.0, that permission has a `protectionLevel` of `signature`. The app must be signed by the signing key used to sign the firmware for you to be able to hold that permission. So, unless you are building your own ROM for Genymotion, I do not see how you can hold that permission.

Comment: I installed an app from the app store, which has that permission so it is possible to obtain that permission.

Comment: Any app can *request* the permission. Apps simply will not get it unless they meet the `protectionLevel`. You are certainly welcome to provide evidence of your claim, including a link to the app in question and details about the device that you installed it on.